# Let A be an open set. If a countable number of points are removed, is the remaining set open?

Tags: real-analysis

How is this counter-example that I just came up with?

Suppose $A = (0, 10)$. This is an open set because it's an open interval. Now, let's remove points $p_i$ such that $p_i = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{i}(1/2)^j$ for $i \in \mathbb N$, and let's consider the point 2. Because as $i \to \infty$, $p_i \to 2$, we can see that no matter how much we shrink an interval around $2$, the interval will always have a "hole" in it.

Part of why I think my counter example may be bogus is that I'm sure whether 2 is even in the new set since technically, in the limit, $p_i = 2$

By the way, the definition of open set I'm using is: an open set is a set such that every point $x$ in the set lies in an open interval $(a,b)$ that is contained in the set.

Comment: Well, we need to start somewhere. What does it mean for a set to be open?

Comment: Why don't you try to be as destructive as you can.  Remove *all* the rational numbers.  That may give you insight then just removing the points one by one.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk has a good point. There are different ways to define an open set on the reals. Also, even when talking about the usual way to define an open set on the reals there are different equivalent definitions.

Comment: Oh, never mind.  You've got the intuition.  Now put it formally.  What if does an "open set mean".   It mean that for every point in the set ..... something..... What is that "something".  Does that something happen at point $2$? (But first of all is $2$ *in* your set?  Was it one of the points you removed?)

Comment: Why are you asking "why is this a counter example"?  It seems to me the explanation you gave shows (albeit it too informally) exactly why it is a counter example.  The set you described is clearly *not* open as the point $2$ (which is in the set) does not have the property required of every point in an open set (in some books that requirement is the definition of being an "interior point")

Comment: @fleablood I came up with that counter example, and I just learned about open sets in class today, so I wasn't sure whether my reasoning was right. More specifically, part of why I think my counter example may be bogus is that I'm sure whether 2 is even in the new set since technically, in the limit, $p_i = 2$

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I updated my post to include the definition of open set I'm using as well as my qualms regarding the counter example I provided.

Comment: Okay, fair questions.  Your counter example is good.  $2$ *is* in the set because to points you are removing-- none of them is $2$.  It doesn't matter that $2$ is the *limit* as you are not removing the limit; you are removing the points but not that limit and the limit is *not* one of the points.  (That's kind of the entire point of analysis!).  Now you are correct that every interval around $2$ "has a hole".  But say it more formally using the definitions and language you are learning.

Comment: "the definition of open set I'm using is: an open set is a set such that every point x in the set lies in an open interval (a,b) that is contained in the set."  Okay, but now we are going to ask you what is the definition of "open interval".    Eventually you have to define out "open" means.

Comment: @fleablood: FYI, I upvoted your comment with the nicely descriptive phrase "be as destructive as you can".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not removing $2$ because $2 \ne p_i = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{i}(1/2)^j$ for any $p_i$. Removing any set of points (countable or not) does not mean removing limit points if the limit point is not one of the points itself.

Now, you intuition is good.  But let's argue it formally.  Let $(a,b)$ but any *arbitrary* open interval so that $2 \in (a,b)$.  This means nothing more or less than $a < 2 < b$.

We want to claim that no matter what  $a$ is, so long as $a < 2$ then there will be a $p_i$ so that $a < p_i < 2$ so $p_i\in ...$, oh, I guess we should give our set a a name....

Let $B = (0,1) \setminus \{p_i| p_i = 1+\sum\limits_{j=1}^i\frac 1{2^j}\}$.  Our goal is to show $B$ is not open.

If it were then there would exist an open interval $(a,b)$ so that $a < 2 < b$ where $(a,b) \subset B$.

We are going to show this is impossible as for *any* $a < 2$ we are going to have some $p_i$ so that $a < p_i < 2$.  This means $p_i\in (a,b)$ and as $p_i \not \in B$ we do *not* have $(a,b)\subset B$ and as this is true for *any* $(a,b)$ where $a< 2$ then this is true for *all* $(a,b)$ so that $a < 2 < b$.

And there for as there is *no* possible $(a,b)$ so that $2\in (a,b)$ and $(a,b)\subset B$.  The definition of "open" fails and $B$ is not an open set.

.... phew... okay, we do that:

You say that $p_i \to 2$ but what does *that* mean?  Well, it means that $2 \ge p_i$ for all $p_i$ and for any $a < 2$ there is some $p_i < 2$.  And that is all we need.

We are done.... if we we assume $p_i \to 2$. But how do we know that?

Well.... It's easy to show by algebra that $p_i = 2-\frac 1{2^{i+1}}$ so to find a $p_i$ so that $a < p_i = 2-\frac 1{2^{i+j}} < 2$ we just need to find an $i$ so that $0 < \frac 1{2^{i+j}} < 2 - a$.

I'm going to assume that has been covered in your class.

.....

tl;dr

Yes, you counter-example is a good one.

======

By the way... He is a more "scorched earth" counter-example.

Take $\mathbb R$ which is open (because for any $(a,b)$ we have $(a,b)\subset \mathbb R$).  Remove $\mathbb Q$ which is a countable set.  We will be left with $\mathbb I = \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q=$ all the irrational numbers.

This is clearly not an open set.  For any irrational number $w$ if we take any interval $(a,b)$ so that $a < w < b$ there will always be some rational $q\in (a,b)$ and $q\in \mathbb Q$ so $q \not \in \mathbb I$ so $(a,b)\not\subset \mathbb I$.

---

It's worth noting that if you take an open set and remove a *finite* number of points then the resulting set *will* be open.  I'll leave you to ponder that.

(Intuitively for any remaining point $x$, $x$ was not one of the removed points.  As there were only a *finite* number of points removed there will be a greatest point $< x$ that was removed (or else no point less than $x$ was removed) and there will be a least point $> x$ that was removed (or ditto).  So the interval between those points will be contained in the set.)

Comment: Ah, I see. I need to get better at using the language of analysis - essentially, formalizing my arguments better. Thank you!

Comment: Well, to be fair I'm going into a lot more detail then I need to.

Answer (score 0):

I think the original argument works. Here's a big picture sketch without any details (those are up to you). If you have trouble with any of these parts those would be good follow-up questions.

Even though $p_i \to 2$, for any actual finite value of $i$ we have $p_i \neq 2$.

Once you've got that, show any interval centered at $2$ will for some value of $i$ contain $p_i$. You can show this using the definition of convergence of $p_i \to 2$.

So then since every interval centered at $2$ contains a $p_i$, which we have subtracted from our set, no such interval can be contained in said set. Therefore, the set can't be open.